# Setting up flask backend in AWS amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I want to setup flask backend in aws amplify, my frontend is react js.

Here is the folder structure:

```
root:
-flask-backend
--flask_app.py
--modules
-react-frontend
```

Note that my flask backend has `app.py` which is the core file and is supposed to backend listening to requests and then `modules` have some of the dependencies (imports) required to run `app.py`

The flow is like this:

react front end requests and fetches data from flask backend and accordingly the pages open. how to set it up? I referred to [this](https://medium.com/@eu.galioto/the-simplest-server-configuration-for-your-aws-amplify-cognito-app-a074c01c743d) medium article but nowhere it's shown how to configure backend based on your path (currently I have put my files in a git repository) so that both frontend and backend run parallely.